# Why doesn't Spring's PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver match "*" with nothing?

Tags: spring

I am trying to get a properties file from within a zip file.  I need to use a wild card, because I will want to match either "my.properties" or "my_en.properties".  I create a `ResourcePatternResolver` like so:

```
ClassLoader loader = MyClass.class.getClassLoader();
ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(loader);
```

I succeed when I try to retrieve the "my.properties" file using no wild card:

```
resolver.getResource("file:C:/somePath/a.zip/META-INF/my.properties").exists()
```

returns `true`.  However, if I add a wild card to the file name, it fails, e.g.,

```
resolver.getResource("file:C:/somePath/a.zip/META-INF/my*.properties").exists()
```

returns `false`.  What can I do to match and retrieve either file?  I am trying to do this in a webapp within Tomcat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is unclear about this, but the `getResource` method does not use PathMatcher internally to resolve the resource (that means that no wildcard is allowed), try `getResources(String locationPattern)` instead.

For example :

```
Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("file:C:/somePath/a.zip/META-INF/my*.properties");

for(Resource resource : resources) {
  // do something for each resource found
}
```

Comment: It seems strange that getResource and getResources do things differently.  Celebrate diversity!

Comment: There is a certain logic in the sense that for a pattern there can always be 0, 1 or n matches for which the method `getRessources` is adapted. On the other hand, the `getResource` documentation makes it clear that the method always returns 1 resource and never null which can not cover the different possible cases.

Comment: Does it work as you expect  ? is my response accepted?

Comment: I like it so far.  I'm just waiting another couple of days to see if I get another answer that I like better.

Comment: One thing to remember here is the use of the unix / vs the microsoft \ in the path. In this case because we're using string the unix / needs to be used and it doesn't need to be escaped. When I got this right, getResources found all 9 of my files. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation explains it:

> **No Wildcards:**
>
> In the simple case, if the specified location path does not start with
>   the "classpath*:" prefix, and does not contain a PathMatcher pattern,
>   this resolver will simply return a single resource via a getResource()
>   call on the underlying ResourceLoader. Examples are real URLs such as
>   "file:C:/context.xml", pseudo-URLs such as "classpath:/context.xml",
>   and simple unprefixed paths such as "/WEB-INF/context.xml". The latter
>   will resolve in a fashion specific to the underlying ResourceLoader
>   (e.g. ServletContextResource for a WebApplicationContext)

For trying anti-patterns, have a look at:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html

Comment: That doesn't explain it to me.  The specified path does not start with the classpath prefix.  Is my specification a PathMatcher pattern?  If it is, shouldn't it return a single resource?  If not, what is the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

How suggest Sébastien Helbert getResource and getResources works very different in fact if you see the original Spring Code you can see a this code:

```
public class PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver implements ResourcePatternResolver {

....
@Override
    public Resource getResource(String location) {
        return getResourceLoader().getResource(location);
    }

    @Override
    public Resource[] getResources(String locationPattern) throws IOException {
        Assert.notNull(locationPattern, "Location pattern must not be null");
        if (locationPattern.startsWith(CLASSPATH_ALL_URL_PREFIX)) {
            // a class path resource (multiple resources for same name possible)
            if (getPathMatcher().isPattern(locationPattern.substring(CLASSPATH_ALL_URL_PREFIX.length()))) {
                // a class path resource pattern
                return findPathMatchingResources(locationPattern);
            }
            else {
                // all class path resources with the given name
                return findAllClassPathResources(locationPattern.substring(CLASSPATH_ALL_URL_PREFIX.length()));
            }
        }
        else {
            // Generally only look for a pattern after a prefix here,
            // and on Tomcat only after the "*/" separator for its "war:" protocol.
            int prefixEnd = (locationPattern.startsWith("war:") ? locationPattern.indexOf("*/") + 1 :
                    locationPattern.indexOf(':') + 1);
            if (getPathMatcher().isPattern(locationPattern.substring(prefixEnd))) {
                // a file pattern
                return findPathMatchingResources(locationPattern);
            }
            else {
                // a single resource with the given name
                return new Resource[] {getResourceLoader().getResource(locationPattern)};
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```

reading the Spring code is clear that getRersources use the AntPattern and geetResource no. I fell it right because with a Wildcards is implicit that you want a multi result and not only one, get resource do not works because it do not take an the common opinion of if I have more that one I take the first, it just do not works because it is no been think in order to works for take the first in case of multi result, it is just a choice.
For this reason the your use case, use the wildcard, can be achieved using the getResources() method

I hope that it can help you to take the right method.