# Java ResourcePatternResolver.getResources doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm trying to make a Spring Batch application that read multiple files for that I'm using a Partitioner class, I'm trying to assign the path where are the multiple files but ResourcePatternResolver.getResources is not working with the wildcard

Here is the code what I have

```
@Bean("partitioner")
    @StepScope
    public Partitioner partitioner() {
        MultiResourcePartitioner partitioner = new MultiResourcePartitioner();
        File resource = new File(glUnprocessedFilesPath);
        ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        Resource[] resources = null;

        try {
            resources = resolver.getResources("file:"+resource.getAbsolutePath()+"\\GLTC_Emergency*");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        partitioner.setResources(resources);
        partitioner.partition(10);
        return partitioner;
    }
```

When I put the hold name of one file in that folder it works but when I try to put the Wildcard is not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't Spring's PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver match "\*" with nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51085357/why-doesnt-springs-pathmatchingresourcepatternresolver-match-with-nothing)

Comment: No, he is talking about getResource method and I'm using getResources, I already read that answer